# How can I completely remove an object from an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have been using the following code:

```
formData.objectiveDetails.push(emptyObjectiveDetail);
```

This pushes a new emptyObjectiveDetail object onto the end of an array called objectiveDetails.

If for example the array of objectiveDetails contains 13 objects then how could I remove the one at position 5? I assume I could make this null but what I want to do is to completely remove it so the length of the array becomes 12.

This might be off topic but I have been considering adding underscore.js.  Is this something that could be done with underscore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using underscore.js

```
objectiveDetails = _.without(objectiveDetails, _.findWhere(arr, {id: 5}));
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Actually it looks a bit more complicated than not using _underscore. If you were doing this would you use splice or underscore?

Comment: Well, if you just needed it for this particular operation, I would go with splice. But if you needed more specific function helpers, then I'd add underscore.js

Answer (score 5):

```
formData.objectiveDetails.splice(5, 1)
```

First argument is the array index and the second the number of items to remove starting from that index.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove the object from the array. Something like this:-

```
formData.objectiveDetails.splice(5, 1)
```

Comment: Okay that looks good. So I guess underscore isn't really needed here. If I was using underscore would there be an equivalent?