# How to remove specific key and value from array object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here I have arrayData array object in this arrayData I have multiple object I want to remove index and type key values from this array object how to remove from this arrayData ?

```
arrayData : [
  0: {
       index: 0
       is_required: true
       name: "vmvdnksl"
       type: "LONG_TEXT"
     }
  1: {
       index: 1
       is_required: true
       name: "dsvnlk"
       type: "MULTIPLE_SELECTORS"
     }
   ]
```

after removiing index and type I want this type result

```
 arrayData : [
  0: {
       is_required: true
       name: "vmvdnksl"
     }
  1: {
       is_required: true
       name: "dsvnlk"
     }
   ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I completely remove an object from an array in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158846/how-can-i-completely-remove-an-object-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Please, update with your expected result. I'm assuming you want the same structure but not showing `index` and `type`, is that correct?

Comment: @Shidersz i update my question

Comment: Ok, one more thing, is `arrayData` an array or an object?

Comment: @Shidersz arrayData is array

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> You can use rest parameter. which will come handy when you have lot's
>   of keys which you want to keep and removing only few of them.

```js
const arrayData= [{index: 0,is_required: true,name: "vmvdnksl",type: "LONG_TEXT"},{index: 1,is_required: true,name: "dsvnlk",type: "MULTIPLE_SELECTORS"}];

const result = arrayData.map(({type,index,...rest}) => ({...rest}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what if there is array of keys  and not separate keys . how to write that I map ??

Comment: @minigeek can you please post an example of what you're stating, btw you can destructure array as well ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses

Comment: yes I tried ..not able to put up proper logic. basically instead of type, index as known keys. i have array of strings which has those keys ['type', 'index'] .. I am passing it as input to my component in angular. your answer is best way to do if we know keys but for now I have to do with delete and filter combination

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and `destructuring` for this task:

```js
const arrayData = [
    {
       index: 0,
       is_required: true,
       name: "vmvdnksl",
       type: "LONG_TEXT"
     },
     {
       index: 1,
       is_required: true,
       name: "dsvnlk",
       type: "MULTIPLE_SELECTORS"
     }
];

let res = arrayData.map(({is_required, name}) => ({is_required, name}));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

I prefer to never mutate the original data, but in the case you need this, you can do this way (or using `delete` as others has shown):

```js
const arrayData = [
    {
       index: 0,
       is_required: true,
       name: "vmvdnksl",
       type: "LONG_TEXT"
     },
     {
       index: 1,
       is_required: true,
       name: "dsvnlk",
       type: "MULTIPLE_SELECTORS"
     }
];

let res = arrayData.forEach(
    ({is_required, name}, idx, arr) => arr[idx] = ({is_required, name})
);
console.log(arrayData);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: is there any possiblity to remove using type and index using index and type not is_required or name?

Comment: @Akki Check the answer given by **Code Maniac** or use `delete` as other answer has shown for what you ask on the first comment. **tip:** to get votes on your question, next time you should provide what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove properties from objects using the `delete` keyword.

```js
var arrayData = [
  0: {
       index: 0,
       is_required: true,
       name: "vmvdnksl",
       type: "LONG_TEXT"
     },
  1: {
       index: 1,
       is_required: true,
       name: "dsvnlk",
       type: "MULTIPLE_SELECTORS"
     }
 ];

for (var i in arrayData) {
  for (var j in arrayData[i]) {
    if (j === 'index' || j === 'type') {
      delete arrayData[i][j];
    }
  }
}

console.log(arrayData);
```

Comment: @Akki I did. Can you press the check mark under the vote of my question and vote it up too? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For Array you can use the `map()` function

```js
    var arrayData = [
      {
           index: 0,
           is_required: true,
           name: "vmvdnksl",
           type: "LONG_TEXT"
      },
      {
           index: 1,
           is_required: true,
           name: "dsvnlk",
           type: "MULTIPLE_SELECTORS"
      }
    ],
    mappedArrayData = arrayData.map(({is_required, name}) => {
       return {is_required, name};
    })
    
    console.log(mappedArrayData);
```

For Object use the `delete` operator.

```js
var arrayData = {
  0: {
       index: 0,
       is_required: true,
       name: "vmvdnksl",
       type: "LONG_TEXT"
     },
  1: {
       index: 1,
       is_required: true,
       name: "dsvnlk",
       type: "MULTIPLE_SELECTORS"
     }
  };
  
  
for (let key in arrayData) {
  delete arrayData[key].index;
  delete arrayData[key].type;
}
  
console.log(arrayData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using JavaScript's [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), as shown in this code example:

```
for(let o in arrayData){
    delete arrayData[o].index;
    delete arrayData[o].type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Array.map()` to show only required properties:

```js
const arrayData= [
   {
       index: 0,
       is_required: true,
       name: "vmvdnksl",
       type: "LONG_TEXT"
     },
   {
       index: 1,
       is_required: true,
       name: "dsvnlk",
       type: "MULTIPLE_SELECTORS"
     }
   ];

const result = arrayData.map(({is_required, name}) => ({is_required, name}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: is there any possiblity to remove using type and index using index and type not is_required or name?

Comment: This is rare, the last answer, clearly showing the same code that much of the others answers already shown, get more upvotes?