# How to remove an item from array object in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to skip/remove an element from array object to display required data only and skip _id
One answer is here but needs more detail

[How to remove specific key and value from array object in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016009/how-to-remove-specific-key-and-value-from-array-object-in-javascript)

```json
[
    {
        _id:"1",
        id:"d8a67aa5-10bd-43bb-be33-5e4219cedaf4",
        title:"Work"
    },
    {
        _id:"2",
        id:"d8a67aa5-10bd-43bb-be33-5e4219cedaf4",
        title:"Work"
    }
]
```

As you can see above the array object has three element, _id, id and title.

I want to achieve this result

```json
[
    {
        id:"d8a67aa5-10bd-43bb-be33-5e4219cedaf4",
        title:"Work"
    },
    {
        id:"d8a67aa5-10bd-43bb-be33-5e4219cedaf4",
        title:"Work"
    }
]
```

I do not want to have _id
I shall be very thankful

Comment: This should work `arr.map(({ _id, ...rest }) => rest)`.

Comment: @SamR. hmm good method, never thought of it.

Comment: Sam R. It work for me. how I can accept you comment. I searched and there is not specific solution like that you porvided.

Comment: @SamR. can you add it like an answer? this will help many people.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` over array and remove the prop you want.

I have create a function `removeProp()` which will remove the any given prop from any array of objects.

```js
const arr = [{
    _id: "1",
    id:"d8a67aa5-10bd-43bb-be33-5e4219cedaf4",
    title:"Work"
},{
    _id: "2",
    id:"d8a67aa5-10bd-43bb-be33-5e4219cedaf4",
    title:"Work"
}]

const removeProp = (arr, prop)=> arr.map(({[prop]:p, ...other}) => other);
console.log(removeProp(arr, "_id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` in conjunction w/ `Array.prototype.reduce` & object spreading to achieve this

```js
const array = [
    {
        _id:"1",
        id:"d8a67aa5-10bd-43bb-be33-5e4219cedaf4",
        title:"Work"
    },
    {
        _id:"2",
        id:"d8a67aa5-10bd-43bb-be33-5e4219cedaf4",
        title:"Work"
    }
]

const createCompactArray = (array, keyToOmit) => array.map(o => Object.keys(o).reduce((o1, k) => (k!==keyToOmit?{ ...o1, [k]: o[k] }:o1), {}))

createCompactArray(array, '_id') // =>

[
    {
        id:"d8a67aa5-10bd-43bb-be33-5e4219cedaf4",
        title:"Work"
    },
    {
        id:"d8a67aa5-10bd-43bb-be33-5e4219cedaf4",
        title:"Work"
    }
]
```

One of the benefits to this approach (having a re-usable function w/ a dynamic key to omit) is that you can use the same approach regardless of what key you want to omit.

You can even enhance this to accept multiple keys!

```js
const createCompactArrayV2 = (array, keysToOmit = []) => array.map(o => Object.keys(o).reduce((o1, k) => (!keysToOmit.includes(k)?{ ...o1, [k]: o[k] }:o1), {}))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just delete the _id field.

```js
arr.forEach((item) => {delete item._id})
```

Comment: Why are you using `map`?

Comment: I've updated my code.